# Concurrency Proof

Tags: geometry

Prove that the line joining the midpoints of opposite sides of a quadrilateral and the line joining the midpoints of the diagonals are concurrent.

I haven't really done concurrency proofs before, but I guess the first part is because the midpoints of sides of any quadrilateral form a parallelogram and diagonals of a parallelogram are concurrent. I need some help with the second part.

Addendum-
In any triangle $ABC$, prove that the bisectors of the interior angle $A$ and exterior angles at $B$ and $C$ are concurrent.

Comment: Since the Addendum has nothing to do with the original question, it "should" be posted separately; however, since you've already provided an answer, it doesn't matter. I'll note that the Addendum follows immediately from [the trigonometric form of Ceva's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Indeed it's all about two different parallelograms formed by two groups of four of these six midpoints. And it is true that the diagonals of a parallelogram intersect, but their intersection point is very special. Special for both diagonals.

Comment: I see what you mean....... Thanks.

Comment: Good job! You are welcome!

Comment: There are actually 3 parallelograms.

Comment: @Hrhm Yes, exactly, but you need only two of them to prove the concurrency.

Comment: Yes, good point.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the addendum of the question is actually quite beautiful. Those who want to see the answer can go here-
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2578